# How Can CLR Be Leveraged In Place of T-SQL Functions to Avoid RBARs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, clr

I need to execute some simple functions like heavisides, binary steps, sigmoids and various tangents repeatedly over some sets of SQL Server data. I've often heard that it's efficient to derive any sets and aggregates used in such functions through T-SQL, but inefficient to execute functions of that sort repeatedly in T-SQL. From what I've read, using T-SQL for that purpose would apparently qualify as a "RBAR" operation, or "Row by Agonizing Row," according to SQL Server guru Jeff Moden's popular term. In various articles scattered across the Internet I've often read that such functions ought to be implemented in C# or VB.Net instead, but I'm unclear as to exactly how I can go about this and still avoid RBARs. Can anyone point me to some best practices for using .Net languages for this purpose? This raises some closely related questions like:

1) Can I do this efficiently in CLR functions?

2) Would it be more efficient to use C# or VB.Net arrays inside such functions and feed them whole sets of data en masse?

3) How could I avoid RBARs in such a design, if I'm still calling the CLR functions once for each record in the set, just as I would with an ordinary SQL Server function?

4) Should such logic instead be captured in middle tier objects and fed data across the network?

5) If I have to execute such functions in occasional batches all day long, can I instead run a C# or VB.net program on the server side and just continuously feed it data? This solution might go with #2, but I imagine it could compromise server stability if allowed to consume too much memory/CPU/IO outside SQL Server's control.

The whole thrust of these questions is mainly directed at one objective: finding the most efficient way to avoid RBARs when executing these functions. If there's some other method of avoiding them that I didn't mention, please let me know. I already know how to avoid some RBARs by using T-SQL to create aggregates and set-based solutions, but I wonder if I can eliminate any others directly related to the repetitive function calls. The best practice seems to be to use .Net instead of SQL Server functions to accomplish this, but I'm fuzzy as to how to implement that in practice. Any help would be appreciated in clarifying this design decision for me.

Comment: Analytical functions are the culprit here. Can you not use a tabular function? Casting and conversions are small costs to running multiple queries every row. Are you sure this is still a relational concern? Then use SQL. Is this is cursive, then use an appropriate method (like .Net, though SQL has its own methods). I guess I am not understanding how you have "simple"  calculations if what you say is true

Comment: Yes, it's definitely relational in that I have to derive some complicated sets before applying these simple math functions (like various step and sigmoids, for example the logistic function - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to each row. The reason I'm not using tabular functions for this is that I'd still have to execute the math functions once for each row (a RBAR) within it, so it wouldn't help optimize things for me at all. I can easily code my own logistic function in T-SQL, but i've heard it'd be more efficient to do that type of thing in C# or VB.Net.

Comment: I might be confused. I meant relational datasets. Set theory. T-SQL does have cursive operations (including XQuery. OPENXML uses sets), but yes, it likely is more efficient to use a cursive language to handle cursive logic.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these functions, like, specifically in code (pseudo or otherwise)?

If you just need to run an arithmetic operation on a set of fields, that can generally be done "inline" (meaning SQL can substitute the approprate code for your function) rather than having to fully execute the function on each row. If you have something thats far more complicated than that, then CLRs might be worth considering. However bear in mind, CLRs come with a whole raft of gotchas and potential security issues which can be difficult to fully account for or get past your DBAs.

Comment: As far as the single issue of whether CLR would be faster than t-sql, it depends and you'll have to figure that out through testing. The classic string split under 8k ascii or 4k unicode is so marginally faster via CRL it's really not worth it.  Parsing large JSON strings (pre sql 2016), it is worth it.  If performance is important, take the time to do both and compare the results against a large dataset with realistic values.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I've recently come across some good sources dredged up from various corners of the Internet that provide exactly the kind of guidance I was looking for. I may post an answer to my own question (based on the information these links provided) in due time, once I verify that they actually address the underlying problems.

Answer (score 0):

No. A CLR is just a function written in .Net and exposed in SQL Server so the SQL engine can call it. They are generally less efficient than an optimized SQL query but allow you to do things that SQL can't, like advanced string manipulation or analytical calculations. As a side-effect, CLR allows web programmers to create code that make sense when SQL is foreign to them, but which also avoids SQL's set-based (non-RBAR), highly-efficient operations.

If your calculations are over the entire data set, like finding the average squirrel weight in a squirrel database, you can use set-based aggregations to get the inputs for a CLR function (SELECT AVG([Weight]) FROM dbo.SQUIRRELS), but if you need a calculation on every row in the data, you're kind of stuck if SQL can't do the calculations.

If you can perform the calculation using SQL, you should create an inline table-valued function that performs the calculation and then use OUTER APPLY to update the calculated field. Here's an explanation if you want to look into this route.
[Rob Farley's SQL Blog](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/).